# Lookup table in Java, convertible to iOS app?

Tags: java, ios, lookup

Working up an iOS app with a lookup table, and intend to use an available routine from the java-sphere, then use a conversion program to make the lookup table functional on iOS.  Need someone to direct me to a free java lookup table, that'll work like this.  Type a 4 digit number into your phone, and it looks up a text description from the table and retrieves/displays that text.
Very much appreciate your help.  Utilito

Comment: "Convert a lookup table" ??? Are you perhaps talking about the Hashtable / HashMap class?

Comment: this is for string and should work with string having sequence of numbers http://stackabuse.com/article/example-code/example-adding-autocomplete-to-jtextfield - put all the list of the text to be autocompleted to into the list in input